# delete overload, recursive overflow

Tags: operator-overloading, stack-overflow

Hey guys i wrote a quick test. I want delete to call deleteMe which will then delete itself. The purpose of this is so i can delete obj normally which are allocated by a lib. (i dont want any crashes due to crt or w/e).

With delete this i get a stackoverflow, without it msvc says i leaked 4 bytes. When i dont call test i leak 0. How do i delete w/o a recursion problem?
-edit-
to make this more clear. I want the LIB to call delete (thus deleteMe) instead of the program due to crt

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual void deleteMe()=0;
    static void operator delete (void* p) { ((B*)p)->deleteMe(); }
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    void deleteMe()      {
        delete this;
    }
};

int test()
{
    B *p = new D;
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion is due to `deleteMe` calling `delete`, which calls B's `operator delete` that calls `deleteMe` again. It's OK to overload `operator delete` (although you usually overload `operator new` as well), especially when handling "foreign" objects which is likely your case, however you must in turn call the actual cleanup routine from within the custom `delete`.

In the general case an overloaded `operator delete` must match the `operator new`. In your case:

```
B *p = new D;
```

Here `p` is allocated with the global `new`, so it must be freed with the global `delete`. So:

```
class D : public B
{
public:
    void deleteMe()      {
        ::delete this;
    }
};
```

Comment: the cleanup routine is mostly in the dtor, i would like to delete the object with normal delete and allocate it with the normal new. How do i do this w/o a recursion problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be overriding delete.  Especially not to a function that ends up calling delete.  Any memory freeing that you need to do (and you don't need to do any in this example) should be done in a destructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off just having a Destroy() method that your clients are expected to call... this will protect your lib from differences in the heap.